# 15 squares into 3 stars

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

You are given $15$ unit squares as shown below:

[image]

You would like to create $3$ six-sided stars as something like shown below by only using given $15$ squares:

[image]

> **How is it possible if possible?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this fit the requirements?

> [image]

Comment: pretty fast deduction :)